# Create a custom button with own action code

Tags: php, yii

I want to create a custom button for my admin page, and write its corresponding action but is not working. Here is my code,

Here is my Code :

admin.php:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'login-form',
'action' => "/ContactlistController/actionSave",
)
);?>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>



ContactlistController.php :
public function actionSave()
{
echo 'hi';
}
```

It says that url is not found.

May i know what is the exact error. And how can i fix this ?

Comment: Can you try to remove the `/` in front of you action? `ContactlistController/actionSave`

Comment: Yes i have tried it. Its still the same

Comment: you are right, that was not the problem.. the problem is you need to put an URL there, not an controller/action name.. see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have an action named : `actionSave` for your controller, you need to do differently, because the action prefix is used to find the action that is called, so if you want to go to `image/takepicture` , you need to have in your `ImageController`,an action named: `actionTakepicture` and in your case,

if you want to have `Contactlist/actionSave`, in your `ContactlistController` you need to have an function named `actionActionsave`,

```
public function actionActionsave(){
...
}
```

and the same is for the name of your controller,

and that is not the default naming convention :D

Comment: Yes I have understood your answer, I tried changing my action name but its still the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is, that you try to set the `action` as the name of the action, but it should be the `url` where the form has to be send to.

[CActiveForm - action](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#action-detail)

That is why you get an error, becasue you give the name of the controller/action instead.

You could try to create a URL e.g. with `createUrl`:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'id'=>'login-form',
  'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl("contactlist/save"),
)
);?>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this. How to redirect it to the code that I have written in actionSave() ?

Comment: this should do it, it should redirect to the URL given. unless you are using AJAX for the submit, but it does not seem to.